# Easiest way to merge sets with non-empty intersection

Tags: python, set

I have this list of sets, `mergeList` and I use code below to merge those sets in mergeList which have non-empty intersection. But it doesn't merge all sets with intersection, i.e, after the while loop, there's still some sets in list with intersection.

```
mergeList = [set([0.5]), set([1.5]), set([2.5]), set([3.5]), set([4.5]), set([5.5]), set([2.5, 6.5]), set([6.5]), set([1.5, 7.5]), set([7.5]), set([8.5]), set([0.5, 9.5]), set([9.5]), set([10.5]), set([11.5]), set([12.5]), set([13.5]), set([2.5, 14.5]), set([14.5]), set([8.5, 15.5]), set([15.5]), set([16.5]), set([15.5, 17.5]), set([13.5, 17.5]), set([17.5]), set([8.5, 18.5]), set([18.5]), set([11.5, 19.5]), set([19.5]), set([4.5, 20.5]), set([10.5, 20.5]), set([20.5]), set([8.5, 21.5]), set([21.5]), set([3.5, 22.5]), set([8.5, 22.5]), set([22.5]), set([11.5, 23.5]), set([23.5]), set([12.5, 24.5]), set([24.5]), set([19.5, 25.5]), set([25.5]), set([12.5, 26.5]), set([26.5]), set([27.5]), set([0.5, 28.5]), set([9.5, 28.5]), set([28.5]), set([11.5, 29.5]), set([23.5, 29.5]), set([29.5]), set([5.5, 30.5]), set([30.5]), set([5.5, 31.5]), set([31.5]), set([2.5, 32.5]), set([32.5]), set([16.5, 33.5]), set([33.5]), set([2.5, 34.5]), set([34.5]), set([2.5, 35.5]), set([16.5, 35.5]), set([35.5]), set([12.5, 36.5]), set([9.5, 36.5]), set([36.5]), set([11.5, 37.5]), set([19.5, 37.5]), set([27.5, 37.5]), set([37.5]), set([38.5]), set([39.5]), set([34.5, 40.5]), set([2.5, 40.5]), set([40.5]), set([29.5, 41.5]), set([41.5]), set([13.5, 42.5]), set([17.5, 42.5]), set([42.5]), set([4.5, 43.5]), set([43.5]), set([5.5, 44.5]), set([44.5]), set([43.5, 45.5]), set([45.5]), set([36.5, 46.5]), set([46.5]), set([19.5, 47.5]), set([47.5]), set([13.5, 48.5]), set([48.5]), set([11.5, 49.5]), set([29.5, 49.5]), set([49.5]), set([9.5, 50.5]), set([50.5]), set([30.5, 51.5]), set([1.5, 51.5]), set([51.5]), set([35.5, 52.5]), set([2.5, 52.5]), set([6.5, 52.5]), set([16.5, 52.5]), set([52.5]), set([53.5]), set([43.5, 54.5]), set([4.5, 54.5]), set([54.5]), set([2.5, 55.5]), set([55.5]), set([1.5, 56.5]), set([56.5]), set([8.5, 57.5]), set([57.5]), set([38.5, 58.5]), set([58.5]), set([13.5, 59.5]), set([48.5, 59.5]), set([59.5]), set([10.5, 60.5]), set([20.5, 60.5]), set([60.5]), set([61.5]), set([9.5, 62.5]), set([62.5]), set([47.5, 63.5]), set([25.5, 63.5]), set([63.5]), set([0.5, 64.5]), set([64.5]), set([46.5, 65.5]), set([65.5]), set([16.5, 66.5]), set([35.5, 66.5]), set([66.5]), set([15.5, 67.5]), set([17.5, 67.5]), set([67.5]), set([16.5, 68.5]), set([68.5]), set([53.5, 69.5]), set([69.5]), set([0.5, 70.5]), set([70.5]), set([51.5, 71.5]), set([1.5, 71.5]), set([71.5]), set([70.5, 72.5]), set([0.5, 72.5]), set([72.5]), set([69.5, 73.5]), set([73.5]), set([1.5, 74.5]), set([56.5, 74.5]), set([74.5]), set([10.5, 75.5]), set([75.5]), set([14.5, 76.5]), set([2.5, 76.5]), set([76.5]), set([19.5, 77.5]), set([77.5]), set([2.5, 78.5]), set([58.5, 78.5]), set([40.5, 78.5]), set([78.5]), set([0.5, 79.5]), set([72.5, 79.5]), set([79.5]), set([39.5, 80.5]), set([80.5]), set([29.5, 81.5]), set([41.5, 81.5]), set([81.5]), set([19.5, 82.5]), set([82.5]), set([37.5, 83.5]), set([11.5, 83.5]), set([19.5, 83.5]), set([83.5]), set([11.5, 84.5]), set([84.5]), set([27.5, 85.5]), set([45.5, 85.5]), set([85.5]), set([64.5, 86.5]), set([0.5, 86.5]), set([86.5]), set([65.5, 87.5]), set([9.5, 87.5]), set([46.5, 87.5]), set([36.5, 87.5]), set([87.5]), set([38.5, 88.5]), set([88.5]), set([34.5, 89.5]), set([58.5, 89.5]), set([89.5]), set([4.5, 90.5]), set([90.5]), set([12.5, 91.5]), set([26.5, 91.5]), set([91.5]), set([64.5, 92.5]), set([92.5]), set([3.5, 93.5]), set([22.5, 93.5]), set([8.5, 93.5]), set([93.5]), set([0.5, 94.5]), set([94.5]), set([48.5, 95.5]), set([42.5, 95.5]), set([13.5, 95.5]), set([95.5]), set([19.5, 96.5]), set([96.5]), set([12.5, 97.5]), set([91.5, 97.5]), set([97.5]), set([20.5, 98.5]), set([4.5, 98.5]), set([98.5]), set([8.5, 99.5]), set([99.5]), set([16.5, 100.5]), set([66.5, 100.5]), set([100.5])]

while i < len(mergeList):
    for j in range(len(mergeList) - 1, i, -1):
        if not mergeList[i].isdisjoint(mergeList[j]):
            mergeList[i] = mergeList[i].union(mergeList[j])
            del mergeList[j]
```

Any idea what is the problem here?

UPDATE: I added some data for sample and I hope it doesn't make question complicated.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What happens? Do you get an error message? If so, post it.

Comment: @user2357112 I made it clear.

Comment: Can you show an example where the output is wrong?

Comment: @kroolik I added data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because two sets might not start to intersect until after you check them for intersection.

Suppose you have sets `A`, `B`, and `C`, where `C` intersects `A` and `B`. You do the following.

1. Check `A` and `B` for intersection. No intersection.
2. Check `A` and `C` for intersection. They intersect, so you replace `A` with `A.union(C)` and remove `C`. Now `A` intersects `B` and `C` is gone.
3. You're done with `A`. You move on to `B`, but there's nothing left to compare it against. You stop.

The simple, quick fix is to keep checking a set for intersections with the other sets until you get through all the other sets without finding any.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I'm over-simplfying the problem, but couldn't you do this?

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a|b, mergeList)
```

Here we define a lambda function to union the sets (which removes duplicate entries in the intersect). Placing this in the `reduce` function will apply it to an accumulated set `a` and each additional set in the list `b`.

Comment: Well, could you provide some explanation about your magic here? Besides, it does not work.

Comment: According to [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), your code is going to merge all the sets in `mergeList`, But I want to merge only sets with intersection.

Comment: So, you're looking for a set containing all items that appear in two or more of the individual sets?

Comment: I'm looking for a list of disjoint sets.

Comment: Now your question makes a lot more sense. The problem with your algorithm seems to be the case of [{0 1} {2 3} {1 3}]. With your algorithm you will get [{0 1} {1 2 3}], when you really want [{0,1,2,3}]. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand the question. The problem is that there may be additional subsequent values that need merged into the ith entry. For this reason you must repeat until no changes are made.

Example:

{ 1 } { 2 } { 2 3 }

The OP's algorithm will merge { 1 } with { 2 } -> {1, 2} {2, 3}.

After this step, it will set i = 1, and no longer look at the {1, 2} set.

```
i = 0
while i < len(mergeList):
    changes = True
    while changes:
        changes = False
        for j in range(len(mergeList) - 1, i, -1):
            if not mergeList[i].isdisjoint(mergeList[j]):
                changes = True
                mergeList[i] |= mergeList[j]
                del mergeList[j]
    i += 1
```